# installation of npm

Tags: linux, npm

I was trying to install npm..

```
└─$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

I got some error/message https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZvGd7Kt96f/

That's very huge that's why I didn't add them here.. Then, I tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I got [these messages](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/36RwNbQxgy/)

I am using Debian Based Linux Distro..

I tried as the website also.https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-npm-and-nodejs-14-x-on-kali-linux/

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I got following error

```
Unpacking nodejs (14.16.1-deb-1nodesource1) over (12.21.0~dfsg-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.16.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/cli.json.gz', which is also in package nodejs-doc 12.21.0~dfsg-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.16.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

On your debian distro can you execute these

```
$> sudo apt-get clean
$> sudo apt-get update # update - Retrieve new lists of packages
$> sudo apt-get upgrade -y # apply/perform upgrade according the list
$> sudo apt-get install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do as Ozgur G said https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645094/464778. But, his answer didn't work for me that's why I am posting an answer.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Both of them worked well...! But, when I upgraded. I got some error

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> nodejs : Depends: libnode72 (= 12.21.0~dfsg-1) but it is not installed
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

So, then I tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Now, working well!!